# what happens if there are two or more different implementations of jre on same platform?

Tags: java, applet, jvmti

I have two jre versions installed on my system (1.3 & 1.5) and i am trying to some java applet programs through internet explorer. All i wanted to know is that how will the web browser select which version of jre to use when the applet program is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the default version of Java.

To change this

1. Go to `Control Panel > Java > Advanced > Default Java for Browsers` and uncheck `Microsoft Internet Explorer`.
2. Go to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre_version_you_need_to_use\bin`, and run `javacpl.exe`. Go to `Advanced > Default Java for Browsers` and check `Microsoft Internet Explorer`.

Comment: how we will know which is the default java version as both the JREs are installed

Comment: @Kratos Control Panel > Java > General > About or just type in command prompt java -version if you set it in the environment variables